# Database replication with old data

Tags: database, mysql, database-replication

I am using MySQL to accomplish Database replication. The replication process is works  very well. What my problem is, the old record is not copied from the master database. Is there is any way to keep the old data in slave database without using mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you - did it wrong... ;)

Before starting your replication you have to initialize your slave server with a complete dump from your master server. for this you need a mysqldump or a backup from your master database.

if it's just that you don't want to stop your master server, you can use perconas hot backup tool to create your initial snapshot: http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup